# Rounding float value off with 0.5 accuracy

Tags: c++, floating-point, numbers

How do you go about rounding a float value with lets say a single number after the decimal point off to for example given 18.0-18.4 I would like to display 18.0 or given 18.5-19.0 show 19.0 etc?
thanks folks

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::round()` as commented by [@Revolver_Ocelot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143242/rounding-float-value-off-with-0-5-accuracy#comment58006643_35143242)

Using `floor(x + 0.5)` has cases where it fails:

1. Negative numbers.  Of course code could attempt `ceil(x - 0.5)` for that.
2. Cases where the sum `x+0.5` may create a rounded answer that is a new integer: The FP number just less than 0.5. Some values where the ULP (the least signification binary digit) of `x` is 0.5 or 1.0.

IOWs, code needs to insure a `0.5` addition does not require extra precision.

Below is a candidate `round_alt()` should `round()` not exist.  `round_alt()` does not have these problems.

```
double round_alt(double x) {
  double ipart;
  // break into integer and fraction parts
  double fpart = modf(x, &ipart);
  if (fpart != 0.0) {
    if (x >= 0.5) {
      ipart += floor(fpart + 0.5);
    } else if (x <= -0.5) {
      ipart += ceil(fpart - 0.5);
    }
  }
  return ipart;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use floor() function. Since round() may not be implemented on your compiler.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double input = 18.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, input += 0.1 )
    {
        double output = floor( input + 0.5 );
        printf( "Input:%f Output:%f\n", input, output );
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Output is like this.

[image]

Comment: Not forgetting to handle negative numbers differently if round towards zero is required. I've never used a C or C++ compiler without `round()` in over 30 years.